# Meteor - iron-router not waiting on subscription data in onBeforeAction hook

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I want to set a `Session` variable (`artistNotAvailable`) when the requested artist is not available. Unfortunately, the route does not work, because it is not waiting on subscription data in my `onBeforeAction` hook. `artistAvail` and `artist` is undefined, but not because there is no artist in the DB, I think it is a subscription problem. I debugged it and calling `Artists.find().fetch();` in the browsers console returned `undefined`.

Here is my route:

```
this.route('eventPage', {
        path: '/event/:slug/:openDate?/:closeDate?',
        onBeforeAction: [teamFilter, function() {
            var event = this.data();
            if (event.outdoor) {
                this.subscribe('artists', this.params.slug);
                if (this.ready()) {
                    var artistAvail = Artists.findOne({eventId: event._id, openDate: moment(this.params.openDate).toDate(), closeDate: moment(this.params.closeDate).toDate()});
                    if ((!this.params.openDate && !this.params.closeDate) || typeof artistAvail === "undefined") {
                        var artist = Artists.findOne({
                            eventId: event._id,
                            openDate: {$lte: new Date()},
                            closeDate: {$gte: new Date()}
                        });
                        if (Artists.find().count() > 0 && artist) {
                            Session.set('artistNotAvailable', true);
                            this.redirect('eventPage', {
                                slug: this.params.slug,
                                openDate: moment(artist.openDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                                closeDate: moment(artist.closeDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                            });
                        } else {
                            Session.set('noArtists', true);
                            this.redirect('overviewPage', {slug: this.params.slug});
                        }
                    } else {
                        this.subscribe('musicOutdoor', this.params.slug, moment(this.params.openDate).toDate(), moment(this.params.closeDate).toDate());
                        if (this.ready()) {
                            var guestsIds = new Array();
                            Guests.find({artistId: artistAvail._id}).forEach(function (guest) {
                                guestIds.push(guest._id);
                            });
                            this.subscribe('guestsOutdoor', guestIds);
                        } else {
                            this.render('loading');
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    this.render('loading');
                }
            } else {
                this.subscribe('musicIndoor', this.params.slug);
                this.subscribe('guestsIndoor', this.params.slug);
                if (!this.ready()) {
                    this.render('loading');
                }
                this.next();
            }
            this.next();
        }],
        waitOn: function() { return [Meteor.subscribe('singleEvent', this.params.slug)]; },
        data: function() {
            return Events.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
        }
    });
```

Subscription:

```
Meteor.publish('artists', function(slug) {
    var event = Events.findOne({slug: slug});
    if (event) {
        return Artists.find({eventId: event._id});
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Now the problem is that when I access the `eventPage` with a wrong `openDate` or `closeDate` I will be redirected to the `overviewPage`, even though there are artists in the db. As already mentioned, I debugged it and it seems to be that `this.ready()` is not working.
I really miss `.wait()` :-(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is a lot of work inside a route.
I am more like subscribing all needed collections in the onBefore and just sending the main data to the template and then using helpers on that template to do the "controller" job. Although it forces me to put so external _id's in most sub collections...

Comment: In Iron Router, I thought to dynamically subscribe to things you put them in the `waitOn`?  Thats what I have been doing, and it seems to work.  Other than that, you could put it in your template's created and unsubscribe in the destroyed.  Also, if you want to set the `this` within the template, you can return any object you want in `data`.  I use that when I need to hook a template into the results of a `Collection.find()` or `Collection.findOne()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. @Guidouil I would like to keep the logic in the `onBeforeAction` if it is possible. @CodeChimp I can't subscribe to all things in `waitOn` because it depends on `event.outdoor` which subscription can be used. It may be a problem because of the `this.next()`. I already asked on SO how it exactly works, but I am still confused where to place it correctly. Basically it should work, the problem is that `this.ready()` is true, but actually it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iron Router works fine.

**this.subscribe** is like **Meteor.subscribe** and Iron-Router doesn't wait for this.

**waitOn** is the function that will wait until each of your returned subscriptions are ready that is why **this.ready()** is true in **onBeforeAction**

There are several ways of doing what you want

- You could do it like CodeChimp said by using templates with create/destroyed
- You could split your route in different routes so that you redirect when it's needed
- you could use **.wait()** from the new API of iron router [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#wait-and-ready).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Replacing `this.subscribe('artists', this.params.slug);` with `this.wait(Meteor.subscribe('artists', this.params.slug));` will result in an exception. Furthermore, I get this warning: `Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?` Where should I place `this.next()`?

Comment: I put the subscription in my `waitOn` function and changed my `publish` logic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to wait for the subscribing (until the subscription is really ready) in data function, like this:

```
Router.route('/:_id', {
    name: 'show',
    template: 'show',
    waitOn: function () {

        var id = this.params._id;
        return Meteor.subscribe('something', id, {});
    },
    data: function () {

        if (this.ready()) {
            var id = this.params._id;
            var data = Somethings.findOne({_id: id});
            return data;
        }
    }
});
```