# Meteor onRendered does not work with ironRouter

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, onrender

My coffeescript

```
Template.shiftDataTable.onRendered ( ->
   App.datatables()
   $('#shift-list-table').dataTable
     pageLength: 10,
     "order":[[0, "asc"]]

   $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Search')
)
```

My jade Template

```
.table-responsive
  table#shift-list-table.table.table-vcenter.table-condensed.table-hover
    thead
      tr
        th Shift Code
        th Shift Type
        th Shift Start Date
    tbody
      each shifts
        tr
          td {{code}}
          td {{type}}
          td {{formatDate createdAt}}
```

The problem is when i go to this page by using ironRouter (Router.go, pathFor), the onRendered will run before the  has been rendered.

Comment: That's a pretty unusual combination, coffee and jade. I assume you could get more answers if you tried to convert to JS and Spacebars. Also the routes information (do you wait on subscriptions?) is incomplete. I'd love to help, but for me there are too many unknowns in your example.

Comment: I've seen this behaviour as well and know what he means. I usually use a `setTimeout` (with 100ms is usually sufficient to simulate a good onReady look&feel). I think it's the subscriptions. Try out this: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#wait-and-ready and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26996765/1523072

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, I use `Tracker.afterFlush()`:

```
Template.shiftDataTable.onRendered ( function () {
  Tracker.afterFlush ( function () {
    App.datatables()
    $('#shift-list-table').dataTable
      pageLength: 10,
      "order":[[0, "asc"]]

    $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Search')
  });
});
```

> Schedules a function to be called during the next flush, or later in
>   the current flush if one is in progress, after all invalidated
>   computations have been rerun. The function will be run once and not on
>   subsequent flushes unless afterFlush is called again.

[Ref](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_afterflush)